# ASP.NET WebForms Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is not registering the script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webforms

So I have this code to register a script in my page:

```
Dim page As Page = HttpContext.Current.Handler
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(AdditionalFieldSave), "mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules" & AdditionalFieldMoreFoundCount,
"<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (typeof(mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules) === 'undefined')
        mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules = {};
    mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules = Object.assign(mandatoryAdditionalFieldRules, {NotesMore" & AdditionalFieldMoreFoundCount & ": {required:true}});
</script>")
```

However when I view the page in a browser, the script does not run and I can't find it in the page source.

The reason I'm declaring the `page` variable rather than using `Me` is because this code is in a VB module intended to be used by multiple pages, rather than an individual page.

Could this have anything to do with the fact that the page I'm trying to inject the script into is being loaded via an AJAX call?

```
// AdditionalFieldHTMLContactType.aspx is the page referenced in the snippet above
jQuery('#ClientCareVisitationContactTypeAdditionalFields').load('../AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldDisplayHTMLContactType.aspx', {/* a bunch of parameters */}, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt == "success"){
        // do successful stuff
    };
    if(statusTxt == "error")
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript? you may have an error when viewing the browser console

Comment: Tried ScriptManager, it didn't work. No errors related to my script. Happens even if I'm not using an AJAX call to load the page.